# Entity-framework 5: How can I query base entities that do not inherit from any derived entities

Tags: inheritance, entity-framework-5

If I have an Employee entity, with derived entity types thus:

```
class Employee
{ // ...
}

class FireWarden : Employee
{ // ...
}

class KeyHolder : Employee
{ // ...
}
```

how can I query Employees that are **neither** fire wardens or key holders, nor any other special type of employee?

Some things I've tried:

```
Employees.OfType<Employee>(). ...
```

returns all employees (as you'd expect).

```
Employees.Where(e => (e.GetType() == TypeOf(Employee)). ...
```

fails with a runtime error saying something along the lines of Entity Framework doesn't support GetType().

I could write

```
var normalEmployees = Employees.Where(e => !(e is FireWarden || e is KeyHolder));
```

but then if I introduce a new entity derived from Employee, I would need to be sure to update all such queries to exclude the new type.

I suppose I could add a "SpecialEmployee" class, deriving from Employee, and derive other types form that. Then I wouldn't have to update all queries, but this feels a bit like the tail is wagging the dog.

Answer (score 1):

If a normal employee cannot be a FireWarden or KeyHolder then you could make a special type for NormalEmployee

Consider the following

```
class Employee
{ // ...
}

class NormalEmployee: Employee
{
    //
}

class FireWarden : Employee
{ // ...
}

class KeyHolder : Employee
{ // ...
}

Employees.OfType<NormalEmployee>()
```

Comment: Good suggestion, thanks. I could also make the base class abstract, so as to avoid confusion.

(The real project is not about employees, but the analogy saves a lot of background!)